# Unable to mount '/dev/sda'

Tags: linux, raid, mount, software-raid, mdadm

My server has two 2 TB hard disk drives in **soft [RAID 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_1)**. I can't mount `/dev/sda`.

#### Output of `parted -l`

```
root@rescue:~# parted -l
Model: ATA HGST HUS724020AL (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name     Flags
 1      20.5kB  1049kB  1029kB                  primary  bios_grub
 2      2097kB  1987GB  1987GB                  primary
 3      1987GB  1992GB  5242MB  ext4            primary
 4      1992GB  2000GB  8388MB  linux-swap(v1)  primary


Error: /dev/sdb: unrecognised disk label
Model: ATA HGST HUS724020AL (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

#### Output of `mount /dev/sda /mnt`

```
root@rescue:/mnt# mount /dev/sda /mnt
mount: block device /dev/sda is write-protected, mounting read-only
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

#### Output of `cat /proc/mdstat`

```
root@rescue:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [multipath] [faulty]
unused devices: <none>
```

How do I get access to my files?

Comment: What do you mean "*in soft RAID-1*"?  I see no evidence that there's software RAID here, and some evidence that there isn't.

Comment: do not mount the harddisk, mount the partition on it..
read the actual error message.

Comment: I think you have to ask yourself, what is most important right now, the learning experience or recovering the data? I have seen people in similar situations who in the end had learned a lesson about what not to do while attempting to recover data.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do not attempt to mount directly the device ! You need to mount a partition of it.

For example, this is **wrong** when you do:

```
mount /dev/sda /mnt
```

What you should do is:

```
mount /dev/sda3 /mnt
```

The system need the meta-data enclosed in the partition to know what to do with it. If you mount directly the device, these meta-data are missing and the mount will fail miserably.

Comment: I think the answer is correct (so upvoted), but the wording is  I feel a bit harsh (particularly as there are rare instances where you would mount /dev/sda) and arguably misleading.  Although it is wrong to do mount /dev/sda /mnt here it simply won't work - it will not harm the disk or screw anything up.

Comment: In my experience, most of those rare instances are the result of poor setup.  +1 for this answer from me, because I think the tone is entirely appropriate.

Comment: @davidgo: I agree that there are a few corner cases where you mount directly the device, and I should have speak about it. Thanks for mentioning it in the comments.